# How to use Apache ivy to resolve dependency with multiple files?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

Here is my ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="spring" name="richclient" rev="1.1.0"/>
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

And ivy-settings.xml:

```
<property name="ivy.local.default.root"             value="/home/---/dev/Java/_libraries/_ivy" override="false"/>
<property name="ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern"      value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" override="false"/>
<property name="ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" override="false"/>
<resolvers>
    <filesystem name="local">
        <ivy pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern}" />
        <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern}" />
    </filesystem>
</resolvers>
```

Ivy try to find
/home/---/dev/Java/_libraries/_ivy/spring/richclient/1.1.0/jars/richclient.jar

And here is the problem. Library has 4 jar files.

How to include all jars in project from one dependency in ivy.xml?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've just downloaded the jars locally? It won't work unless you also write an ivy.xml file for the downloaded files, listing the artifacts that are associated with the module (See *publications* section of the ivy.xml doco)

Why not avoid the hassle of maintaining the your own version of someone else's module by using the maven repository provided by Spring?

Add the following to your **ivy-settings.xml** file:

```
<resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="spring-rcp" m2compatible="true" root="http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/maven2repository"/>
</resolvers>
```

Answer (score 0):

While Ivy can work using dependencies on individual JAR files, it works better if you define separate `ivy.xml` files for the dependencies themselves, which specifies the 4 separate JAR files. This `ivy.xml` defines what Ivy calls a module.

Your application's `ivy.xml` then expresses a dependency on that module, rather than on specific JAR files.

The Ivy website has a tutorial on modules, I highly recommend reading it

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/conf.html